# Code First Migrations: Alpha 3 installation for Offline PCs

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to use Incremental Database Building Feature with Code First Pattern.
So I am looking at this NuGet Link..

1. http://nuget.org/packages/entityframework.migrations
2. http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console

After that, 
I think that If my PC is offline which is not connected to Internet, 
then I don't know how could I install this API.

If Someone know how to install [Code First Migrations: Alpha 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-released.aspx) for offline pc, 
Please let me know the way.

Answer (score 0):

If your development computer doesn't have access to the internet, you can still make use of NuGet by using a local feed (see [Hosting Your Own Nuget Feeds](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)). After you set up a local feed, copy any nupkg files you'll need into the feed's source directory and continue to use NuGet as normal in your projects.